# Programmatically enforce TypeScript contract between frontend and backend API REST responses

Tags: typescript, npm

I'm currently working on an application that uses TypeScript for both frontend(typical "single page" RIA app) and backend(NodeJs) components.

I find this process of duplicated interfaces/types rather annoying and error-prone.

If possible I would like to keep both apps separate and not merging both as a monorepo.

A shared npm package(just for types) might be a good solution but I'm wondering what's the process might look like because those types are changing pretty often and I don't want to publish and install them every time in development. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: “but I'm wondering what's the process might look like” - that’s called [semver](https://semver.org)

Comment: @emix semver does not enforce anything though, it's purely a convention based on faith and hope, while OP is seeking for a compiler-guaranteed solution.

Comment: You can use `npm link` or yarn workspaces during development.

Comment: @Evert if you want to post it as an answer rather than a comment I'll accept it. Thanks